# Why does div inherit parent properties then class properties?

Tags: css

Index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/purecss@2.0.3/build/pure-min.css" integrity="sha384-cg6SkqEOCV1NbJoCu11+bm0NvBRc8IYLRGXkmNrqUBfTjmMYwNKPWBTIKyw9mHNJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="pure-g">
            <div class="pure-u-1-3"></div>

            <div class="pure-u-1-3 content">
                hi
                <h1>IP Manager</h1>
                <br>
                <h3>IP Space</h3>

                <div class="pure-g" style="width:100%">
                    <div clas="pure-u-1-3 card" style="width:100%">span>test<span></div>
                    <div clas="pure-u-1-3 card" style="width:100%"> ... </div>
                    <div clas="pure-u-1-3 card" style="width:100%"> ... </div>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="pure-u-1-3"></div>
        </div>


        <script src="" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

stylesheets.css

```
.content {
    background-color: #edf2f4;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.card {
    background-color: #f0efeb;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
```

relevant pure-min.css:

```
.pure-g {
    letter-spacing: -.31em;
    text-rendering: optimizespeed;
    font-family: FreeSans, Arimo, "Droid Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
    align-content: flex-start
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast:none),
(-ms-high-contrast:active) {
    table .pure-g {
        display: block
    }
}

.opera-only :-o-prefocus,
.pure-g {
    word-spacing: -.43em
}

.pure-u {
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-rendering: auto
}

.pure-g [class*=pure-u] {
    font-family: sans-serif
}
```

First Div Tree:

https://prnt.sc/sz4o61

Div Tree in Div Tree:

https://prnt.sc/sz4p3w

Problem: Alright here the issue. Whenever I render the site in chrome. For the first div 
'pure-g' and child divs with class 'pure-u-1-3' the child div's inherit properties from pure-u-1-3 first then pure-g. Hence for all text in pure-u-1-3 the line-spacing:normal and line-spacing:-0.43em is crossed out. For the next div tree which is inside 'pure-u-1-3 content', the setup is the same and the structure is the same but for some reason I can't explain. The text appears with line-spacing:-0.43 and line-spacing:normal is crossed.

Why does this happen? shouldn't div's inherit from their class first then parent, and ignore anything that was said in class first in the parent?